# Can I use my student ID (private school) as ID proof at the airport security and flight check in, I am an unaccompanied minor travelling domestically

Tags: paperwork, india, minors, identity-cards

I have to urgently travel to Delhi from Varanasi and the only identification proof I have is my ID card of my school (it's a private school, not a government school). I am 16 years old and travelling as an unaccompanied minor. Will my school ID proof be enough to board the flight or is a government ID absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 2):

This site [Documents Required for Domestic Travel in Air India](https://www.ixigo.com/air-india-travel-documents-story-1175272) says about ID documents:

> **Below are the documents required for domestic travel in Air India**
>
> An ID card (Passport, Voter Photo Identity card issued by Election Commission of India, Aadhaar or m-Aadhaar issued by Unique Identification Authority of India (UIDAI), PAN Card issued by Income Tax Department, Driving Licence issued by RTO, Service Photo Identity Card issued by Central / State Government, Public Sector Undertakings, local bodies or Public Limited Companies, ***Student Photo Identity Cards issued by Government Institutions/ Government recognized Educational Institutions***, Nationalised Bank Passbook with attested Photograph, Pension card / Pension documents having photograph of the passenger, Disability Photo ID Card / handicapped medical certificate issued by the respective State / UT Governments / Administrations).

(The original source of this information at [Air India](https://www.airindia.com/in/en/travel-information/visa-documents/documents-required.html) was found by @NicolasFormichella)

So if your ID is *photo ID* and your private school is recognised by the Government as such, you should be OK. They also accept certain bank photo ID.

But the best thing is to contact the airline itself.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella that is not how the site was formatted, and you've broken the link to it.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I was trying to change the link to the official page of Air India on it but the link I had was bad

Comment: I agree your formatting was clearer (maybe the site should have been like that).

Comment: If you want, the link for Air India's page is [this one](https://www.airindia.com/in/en/travel-information/visa-documents/documents-required.html)